# Scope of variables in functions using javascript

Tags: javascript, scope

1. Why the y is leaked outside the function as scope in JavaScript are bound to functions.
2. A detailed explanation would be fruitful.

   ```
   var x = 0;
   function f(){
      var x = y = 1; // x is declared locally. y is not!
       };
   f();
   console.log(x, y); // 0, 1
   ```

Comment: What is there to explain. X is not in the global scope (at least the one you use in your function). Y IS in the global scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just syntax error.
The line `var x = y = 1;` Means:

1. Declare local variable x,
2. y = 1,
3. Declare global variable y (since it's not declared)
4. x = y;

Replace

```
var x = y = 1;
```

with

```
var x = 1, y = 1;
```

or

```
var x = 1;
var y = 1;
```

and you will get local variable y

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp

Comment: In another words you can declare variables (var x,y;) then use them,
or declare with assignment (var x=1, y=1;) using comma, but the line var x = y = 1; interpreter understand as 4 actions, 1) local var x 2)create global variable y (since it's not declared) 3) x=y 4) y=1

Comment: var x = y = 1;
Equals to the code -
var x;
y = 1;
x = y;

Comment: You should edit your first comment as it's wrong (the order of the statement evaluation), instead of the second one (which gets it right). The way it is now (two different comments where the first one is problematic) can be confusing...

Answer (score 0):

The reason the y variable is global is that in Javascript if you omit the `var` keyword from an assignment statement, the variable the value is assigned to is declared on the global object.

That means that if you wrote the f() function this way, declaring both x and y with the `var` keyword:

```
function f(){
    var x, y;
    x = y = 1;
};
```

Then both x and y would be local variables (local x shadowing the global one).

It's bad practice to assign a variable without declaring it (with the var keyword).
New versions of JS will throw an error on this. You can use EC5's strict mode to take advantage of this behavior: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode

so you'd write your function this way:

```
 function f(){
        'use strict'
        var x, y;
        x = y = 1;
    };
```

now if you forget to declare y you get an error yelling at you to do so.